# How to generate compressed public key in bitcoin format, using openssl and the command line?

Tags: terminal, openssl, bitcoin

I am using this line

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -pubout -outform DER | tail -c 65 | xxd -p -c 65
```

which produces an uncompressed bitcoin public key, for instance:

```
049ddf875b4a6e57d31004926bd8331271b4b45731be5c17ea841c89353cbd13adc9cc2347ae1bcb4ed369fd6bfc44040ffda9f8e68f86a6593c94261fc42eca35
```

The prefix 04 indices that this public key contains both the x and y coordinates of the point on the EC. What is the correct way to create the compressed version of this key?

How do I produce a compression version of a private key?

Comment: Try this script: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56680/openssl-generate-bitcoin-address

Comment: @Pak that was indeed the script I was trying but it produces uncompressed public keys. I think my edit produces compressed public keys correctly.

Comment: Another way is to let openssl do the hex and then tidy it up: `(gen/read) | openssl ec -conv_form compressed -noout -text | awk -vORS= '/^pub:/{x=1;next} /^ASN/{exit} x{gsub(/[ :]/,""); print}' ` or `... | sed -n '/^pub/,/^ASN/p' | sed '1d;$d' | tr -d ' :\n'`

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@Anon21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110432/anon21)'s question post.

> found the answer:
>
> ```
> openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -pubout -conv_form compressed -outform DER | tail -c 33 | xxd -p -c 65
> ```